# ES6 super() in constructor and prototype methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, super, es6-class, function-prototypes

I have two questions
First :
I recently learnt that in ES 6 derived class, if super() is not called, the "this" is not available. 
I understand why it is done this way, but I want to know conceptually, what piece of ES6 compiled code is making "this" to be unavailable. I mean if i want to do the same in ES5 to make "this" unavailable, how can that be done.

Second:
Why are we not able to instantiate ES6 prototype methods
Below will not work-

```
class abc{
func(){}
}

var a = new abc()
var b = new a.func()
```

whereas this will work-

```
function abc(){}

abc.prototype.func = function(){}

var a = new abc()
var b = new a.func()
```

WHY ? For the above question as well, I want to know more about what implementation is doing this and not why they decided to provide this feature.

Comment: in ES5 you can't instantiate a function, im sure it will work if you just do var b= a.func()

Comment: Please ask one question, not two.

Answer (score 4):

> I mean if i want to do the same in ES5 to make "this" unavailable, how can that be done.

It's not possible. This behaviour is new in ES6 (and really hard to transpile).

> Why are we not able to instantiate ES6 prototype methods Below will not work

Because method definitions, similar to arrow functions, are no constructors. Unlike `function` expression that can be both called and constructed.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 classes that use extend instantiate objects kind of in a different way from constructors.

When you do `new something()` for constructors, there's a new object instantiated and available through `this`. While ES6 classes that extend other classes will go up the chain and instantiate the base object, thanks to `super()`.

In other words:

```
class C extends B {}
class B extends A {}
class A {}
new C();
```

Will actually travel all the way to A and see that's not a class that uses extend and will instantiate that one (with a twist, the prototype of the object will be the prototype of the `C`). `super` calls on C and B will set the `this` to whatever super returned.

This is why `this` is never set before `super()` because classes that extend something will not create a new object by themselves.

Regarding point 2, the class elements are methods (which can't be constructed), whereas functions on the prototype of constructors are normal functions that work as constructors.